# Jira via docker-compose crashes on startup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jira

I'm having trouble starting jira from via docker-compose. I want a reproducible runtime including keyloak to test a jira-keycloak-auth-mechanism. But everytime I start my env usind docker-compose Jira crashes on startup when initalising the plugin system. I tried jira with its embedded H2 db and (because I thought jira would use to much memory with H2) with postgres. Connecting to postgtes works, in lofile jira states, that the db connection works. This is my docke-dompose.yml with postgres:

```
version: '3'
services:

  mailslurper:
    container_name: mailslurper
    image: marcopas/docker-mailslurper:latest
    networks:
      - jiranet
    ports:
      - "2500:2500"
      - "9090:8080"

  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: jboss/keycloak:latest
    depends_on:
      - mailslurper
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    networks:
      - jiranet
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: atlassian
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: atlassian
      POSTGRES_DB: jiradb
      POSTGRES_ENCODING: UTF8
      POSTGRES_COLLATE: C
      POSTGRES_COLLATE_TYPE: C
    networks:
      - jiranet

  jira:
    container_name: jira
    image: atlassian/jira-software:8.5.0
    depends_on:
      - db
      - keycloak
      - mailslurper
    volumes:
      - jiradata:/var/atlassian/jira
    networks:
      - jiranet
    ports:
      - 9080:8080
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/Berlin
      JVM_MINIMUM_MEMORY: 1024m
      JVM_MAXIMUM_MEMORY: 4096m
      JVM_RESERVED_CODE_CACHE_SIZE: 1024m
      ATL_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/jiradb
      ATL_JDBC_USER: atlassian
      ATL_JDBC_PASSWORD: atlassian
      ATL_DB_DRIVER: org.postgresql.Driver
      ATL_DB_TYPE: postgres72


volumes:
  jiradata:
    external: false
  pg_data:
    external: false


networks:
  jiranet:
    driver: bridge
```

The Mailslurper is just a lightwight smtp dummy to enable mail support for keycloak and jira without actually sending emails.

Here is some (truncated) log output from docker-compose

```
[...]

jira           |     ****************
jira           |     JIRA starting...
jira           |     ****************
jira           |

[...]

jira           |
jira           |     ___ Environment _____________________________
jira           |
jira           |          JIRA Build                                    : 8.5.0#805000-sha1:facbf8be6a56ed8ab71dea158b6e159962506101
jira           |          Build Date                                    : Fri Oct 18 00:00:00 CEST 2019
jira           |          JIRA Installation Type                        : Standalone
jira           |          Application Server                            : Apache Tomcat/8.5.42 - Servlet API 3.1
jira           |          Java Version                                  : 1.8.0_252 - AdoptOpenJDK
jira           |          Current Working Directory                     : /var/atlassian/application-data/jira
jira           |          Maximum Allowable Memory                      : 3641MB
jira           |          Total Memory                                  : 981MB
jira           |          Free Memory                                   : 750MB
jira           |          Used Memory                                   : 231MB
jira           |          Memory Pool: Code Cache                       : Code Cache: init = 33554432(32768K) used = 9983104(9749K) committed = 33554432(32768K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
jira           |          Memory Pool: Metaspace                        : Metaspace: init = 0(0K) used = 21159384(20663K) committed = 21757952(21248K) max = -1(-1K)
jira           |          Memory Pool: Compressed Class Space           : Compressed Class Space: init = 0(0K) used = 2369640(2314K) committed = 2621440(2560K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
jira           |          Memory Pool: PS Eden Space                    : PS Eden Space: init = 268435456(262144K) used = 219819544(214667K) committed = 268435456(262144K) max = 1342177280(1310720K)
jira           |          Memory Pool: PS Survivor Space                : PS Survivor Space: init = 44564480(43520K) used = 24696824(24117K) committed = 44564480(43520K) max = 44564480(43520K)
jira           |          Memory Pool: PS Old Gen                       : PS Old Gen: init = 716177408(699392K) used = 8192(8K) committed = 716177408(699392K) max = 2863661056(2796544K)
jira           |          JVM Input Arguments                           : -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/atlassian/jira/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=32m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Datlassian.standalone=JIRA -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true -Dmail.mime.decodeparameters=true -Dorg.dom4j.factory=com.atlassian.core.xml.InterningDocumentFactory -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT -Djira.home=/var/atlassian/application-data/jira -Datlassian.plugins.startup.options=-fg -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Xloggc:/opt/atlassian/jira/logs/atlassian-jira-gc-%t.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCCause -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -Dcatalina.base=/opt/atlassian/jira -Dcatalina.home=/opt/atlassian/jira -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/atlassian/jira/temp
jira           |          Java Compatibility Information                : JIRA version = 8.5.0, Java Version = 1.8.0_252
jira           |
jira           |     ___ Java System Properties _________________
jira           |
jira           |          atlassian.plugins.startup.options             : -fg
jira           |          atlassian.standalone                          : JIRA
jira           |          awt.toolkit                                   : sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
jira           |          catalina.base                                 : /opt/atlassian/jira
jira           |          catalina.home                                 : /opt/atlassian/jira
jira           |          catalina.useNaming                            : true
jira           |          common.loader                                 : "${catalina.base}/lib",
jira           |                                                          "${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar",
jira           |                                                          "${catalina.home}/lib",
jira           |                                                          "${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar"
jira           |          file.encoding                                 : UTF-8
jira           |          file.encoding.pkg                             : sun.io
jira           |          ignore.endorsed.dirs                          :
jira           |          java.awt.graphicsenv                          : sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
jira           |          java.awt.headless                             : true
jira           |          java.awt.printerjob                           : sun.print.PSPrinterJob
jira           |          java.class.version                            : 52.0
jira           |          java.home                                     : /opt/java/openjdk/jre
jira           |          java.io.tmpdir                                : /opt/atlassian/jira/temp
jira           |          java.locale.providers                         : COMPAT
jira           |          java.naming.factory.initial                   : org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory
jira           |          java.naming.factory.url.pkgs                  : org.apache.naming
jira           |          java.protocol.handler.pkgs                    : org.apache.catalina.webresources
jira           |          java.runtime.name                             : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
jira           |          java.runtime.version                          : 1.8.0_252-b09
jira           |          java.specification.name                       : Java Platform API Specification
jira           |          java.specification.vendor                     : Oracle Corporation
jira           |          java.specification.version                    : 1.8
jira           |          java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory : org.apache.catalina.startup.SafeForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory
jira           |          java.util.logging.config.file                 : /opt/atlassian/jira/conf/logging.properties
jira           |          java.util.logging.manager                     : org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
jira           |          java.vendor                                   : AdoptOpenJDK
jira           |          java.vendor.url                               : http://java.oracle.com/
jira           |          java.vendor.url.bug                           : http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
jira           |          java.version                                  : 1.8.0_252
jira           |          java.vm.info                                  : mixed mode
jira           |          java.vm.name                                  : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
jira           |          java.vm.specification.name                    : Java Virtual Machine Specification
jira           |          java.vm.specification.vendor                  : Oracle Corporation
jira           |          java.vm.specification.version                 : 1.8
jira           |          java.vm.vendor                                : AdoptOpenJDK
jira           |          java.vm.version                               : 25.252-b09
jira           |          jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize                    : 2048
jira           |          jira.home                                     : /var/atlassian/application-data/jira
jira           |          mail.mime.decodeparameters                    : true
jira           |          org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK : 0027
jira           |          org.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER : true
jira           |          org.dom4j.factory                             : com.atlassian.core.xml.InterningDocumentFactory
jira           |          os.arch                                       : amd64
jira           |          os.name                                       : Linux
jira           |          os.version                                    : 4.9.184-linuxkit
jira           |          package.access                                : sun.,
jira           |                                                          org.apache.catalina.,
jira           |                                                          org.apache.coyote.,
jira           |                                                          org.apache.jasper.,
jira           |                                                          org.apache.tomcat.
jira           |          package.definition                            : sun.,
jira           |                                                          java.,
jira           |                                                          org.apache.catalina.,
jira           |                                                          org.apache.coyote.,
jira           |                                                          org.apache.jasper.,
jira           |                                                          org.apache.naming.,
jira           |                                                          org.apache.tomcat.
jira           |          server.loader                                 :
jira           |          shared.loader                                 :
jira           |          sun.arch.data.model                           : 64
jira           |          sun.boot.library.path                         : /opt/java/openjdk/jre/lib/amd64
jira           |          sun.cpu.endian                                : little
jira           |          sun.cpu.isalist                               :
jira           |          sun.io.unicode.encoding                       : UnicodeLittle
jira           |          sun.java.command                              : org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
jira           |          sun.java.launcher                             : SUN_STANDARD
jira           |          sun.jnu.encoding                              : UTF-8
jira           |          sun.management.compiler                       : HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
jira           |          sun.os.patch.level                            : unknown
jira           |          tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.byte.enabled      : true
jira           |          tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan : 

[...]

jira           |          tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip : 

[...]

jira           |          user.country                                  : US
jira           |          user.dir                                      : /var/atlassian/application-data/jira
jira           |          user.home                                     : /var/atlassian/application-data/jira
jira           |          user.language                                 : en
jira           |          user.name                                     : jira
jira           |          user.timezone                                 : Europe/Berlin
jira           |
jira           | 04-Jun-2020 11:50:13.012 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

[...]

jira           |
jira           |     Database configuration OK
jira           |
jira           |     ___ Database Configuration _________________
jira           |
jira           |          Loading entityengine.xml from                 : file:/opt/atlassian/jira/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/entityengine.xml
jira           |          Entity model field type name                  : postgres72
jira           |          Entity model schema name                      : public
jira           |          Database Version                              : PostgreSQL - 9.6.18
jira           |          Database Driver                               : PostgreSQL JDBC Driver - 42.2.6
jira           |          Database URL                                  : jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/jiradb
jira           |          Database JDBC config                          : postgres72 jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/jiradb
jira           |
jira           | 2020-06-04 12:07:20,771 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.jira.startup.JiraStartupLogger]
jira           |
jira           |     ___ Starting the JIRA Plugin System _________________
jira           |
jira exited with code 137
```

This is the end of the docker-compose startup. Jira crashes with memory issue immediately. This is the last line from my log. There are no postgres-errors logged. Keycloak from the same docker-compose works fine, only jira crashes. The conclusion "memor issue" is based on https://success.docker.com/article/what-causes-a-container-to-exit-with-code-137.

The suggested `docker inspect jira` from the link shows:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "003a6189f27a2f1da2270bcb51a535670d33da12fceb39618da3b0e6b3b18724",
        "Created": "2020-06-04T09:50:04.3829194Z",
        "Path": "/tini",
        "Args": [
            "--",
            "/entrypoint.py"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 137,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-06-04T10:07:01.6026135Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2020-06-04T10:08:45.7057606Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:092218bb3b6fd033619595a10279d95062f1258c9396c52f6cdd6591138e0faf",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/003a6189f27a2f1da2270bcb51a535670d33da12fceb39618da3b0e6b3b18724/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/003a6189f27a2f1da2270bcb51a535670d33da12fceb39618da3b0e6b3b18724/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/003a6189f27a2f1da2270bcb51a535670d33da12fceb39618da3b0e6b3b18724/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/003a6189f27a2f1da2270bcb51a535670d33da12fceb39618da3b0e6b3b18724/003a6189f27a2f1da2270bcb51a535670d33da12fceb39618da3b0e6b3b18724-json.log",
        "Name": "/jira",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "localhost_jiradata:/var/atlassian/jira:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "localhost_jiranet",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "9080"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Capabilities": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0a12da3b455083c0d444cc84c9333d43d4f138cdc62ee2ad64409af20b0ce79e-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/425a7af95ef3a12227dbe4964df982e887374c1d3973daf40418abec835f0a5a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7f48eef50519675bdb7f938d64fe233a11b63490341c0029b6d3eaeb5388fa5f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/afbe2372cc44272bc9b23f8eb878dd5a17129b93085acb3c1a2645a09c0618c1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/355db8ad824e7de672c4096761337841d538831986713464f0814ae5183ac2d4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/876bed9e38b1eb774299f436c874fae30a48750bd0c20babd008dd612001ca72/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d5c15355534ccf8fb616926362aeb42a2b5549aa3bce5859367fafe81099b4d1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bd471e038cadb36ae63921335020b101501c3d13d1ea60f1bba4940ae7c138f1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2bf459cba66d584eccd9abad0e335e86959ee2729779be8767beb36fb7af0048/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b974fe9809ed31e49bd2d0ce1280df235032b920fa881f7ee7d9a5aa25072500/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b5ba19f62ac2436051aadd51c42d3c7a2499b8db81f6bb3e48516838c561c551/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cff4baf028474a41eebdaaf29c0512fe4dc53fc19ad5404b4bac9a5240de7243/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/325c13f737a75a2ba79e151686205d69c3e77a83f42424329093e39102334822/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/de3c2e469a142e5dfe4ebc0ca65745864dffec33921b8f6e6d598c63cdbb2525/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9bfe09a50bce35b102c0a517fcd5681992baef62a3673cfbc5bd5953593a22b7/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0a12da3b455083c0d444cc84c9333d43d4f138cdc62ee2ad64409af20b0ce79e/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0a12da3b455083c0d444cc84c9333d43d4f138cdc62ee2ad64409af20b0ce79e/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0a12da3b455083c0d444cc84c9333d43d4f138cdc62ee2ad64409af20b0ce79e/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "2b4a3799530904fc75128956c5350398468b81dd09310faf5ea5b2ee9280a411",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/2b4a3799530904fc75128956c5350398468b81dd09310faf5ea5b2ee9280a411/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/atlassian/application-data/jira",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "localhost_jiradata",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/localhost_jiradata/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/atlassian/jira",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "003a6189f27a",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8080/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "TZ=Europe/Berlin",
                "JVM_MINIMUM_MEMORY=1024m",
                "JVM_MAXIMUM_MEMORY=4096m",
                "JVM_RESERVED_CODE_CACHE_SIZE=1024m",
                "ATL_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/jiradb",
                "ATL_JDBC_USER=atlassian",
                "ATL_JDBC_PASSWORD=atlassian",
                "ATL_DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver",
                "ATL_DB_TYPE=postgres72",
                "PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
                "LANGUAGE=en_US:en",
                "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_VERSION=jdk8u252-b09",
                "JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk",
                "RUN_USER=jira",
                "RUN_GROUP=jira",
                "RUN_UID=2001",
                "RUN_GID=2001",
                "JIRA_HOME=/var/atlassian/application-data/jira",
                "JIRA_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/atlassian/jira"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/entrypoint.py"
            ],
            "Image": "atlassian/jira-software:8.5.0",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/atlassian/application-data/jira": {},
                "/var/atlassian/jira": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/var/atlassian/application-data/jira",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/tini",
                "--"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "2dd9f7c740d03afb36a7b0dcdce18659707b3934c5f7944d01bebe588af37b9e",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "localhost",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "docker-compose.yml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/mnt/c/Entwicklung/home/_workspace/workspace/antora-jira-operations-manual/src/setup/localhost",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "jira",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.5"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "6a75eaea766f5fe6477e31e9ac7430135c1e3f263aab900560d1be25882a95d7",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/6a75eaea766f",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "localhost_jiranet": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "jira",
                        "003a6189f27a"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "927565fdd832e7d93f9a34ae3987f37aff119ce6df537a1a1d9caca0a41dfce9",
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

When I start jira alone without any other containers and with plain docker (so no docker-compose) jira works perfectly fine. For the working docker-only version (no docker-compose) I followed the instructions from https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/jira-software. In the end this was the only command I entered:
`docker volume create --name jiraVolume && docker run -v jiraVolume:/var/atlassian/application-data/jira --name="jira2" -p 8080:8080 atlassian/jira-software:8.5.0`

I have no clue how to fix my jira with docker-compose. Can anyone give me a hint? I'm runnng docker and docker-compose on Windows  via WSL. But running both commands via powershell (so no WSL) brings the same result.

Comment: Exit code 137 can often mean your container was killed due to memory constraints. See e.g. [this artcle](https://success.docker.com/article/what-causes-a-container-to-exit-with-code-137).

Comment: Found it ... the explanation is rather simple. The Docker Desktop App for Windows only allocates a certain amount of memory. I tried to start Jira with 4GB Memory while Docker only allocated 2GB. So the hungriest container (in my case jira) crashed. Can be changed in Docker Desktops "Advanced" Settings. Didn't think of this because Docker does not behave like this on linux systems.